# Tricking libdc1394

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, v4l, libdc1394

I have a third party vision library that would only work with a firewire camera, is it possible to somehow trick libdc1394 into thinking that there is a firewire camera connected but pass frames from a usb webcam via v4l?

Answer (score 0):

Given that stackoverflow is about programming...

You cannot trick libdc1394 however you can write a library that exposes exactly the same API as libdc1394 and use this as a shim over a USB webcam library. Since this is Linux you can start from the source of libdc1394 which will be a lot easier than reverse engineering.